# Horizontal alignment from `align` with numbering from `equation`

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, align

I would like to make the horizontal alignment of the `aligned` environment match that of `align`. I like to group and align a set of equations that belong together, and I like that `equation`+`aligned` gives my one vertically centered equation number. However, the horizontal spacing of `align` is better. In the particular example below, I could of course use two `\notag`'s but what if there were eight lines of equations? Is there a simple way to achieve the best of both worlds?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\noindent This display has nice alignment:
\begin{align}
    E(y) &= \mu_y, & V(y) &= \sigma_y^2,\\
    E(x) &=\mu_x,  & C(x) &= \Sigma_x,\\
    E(\epsilon) &= 0 \quad\text{and} & V(\epsilon) &= \sigma_\epsilon^2.
\end{align}
This display has a single number:
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    E(y) &= \mu_y, & V(y) &= \sigma_y^2,\\
    E(x) &=\mu_x,  & C(x) &= \Sigma_x,\\
    E(\epsilon) &= 0 \quad\text{and} & V(\epsilon) &= \sigma_\epsilon^2.
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: Display of equation alignments.]

Comment: The internal forms of the alignment environments do not have the generous horizontal spacing of the normal forms. Just put a `\qquad` at the beginning of the second column.

Comment: @campa Actually, `\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad` is what gets me there in this example. :)

Comment: `\hspace{7em}` is easier. But you got the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Note `alignedat` gives you full control on the spacing between alignment columns. Here are three possibilities:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\noindent This display has nice alignment:
\begin{align}
    E(y) &= \mu_y, & V(y) &= \sigma_y^2,\\
    E(x) &=\mu_x, & C(x) &= \Sigma_x,\\
    E(\epsilon) &= 0 \quad\text{and} & V(\epsilon) &= \sigma_\epsilon^2.
\end{align}
These displays have a single number (each):
\begin{equation}
  \begin{alignedat}{2}
    E(y) &= \mu_y, & V(y) &= \sigma_y^2,\\
    E(x) &=\mu_x, & C(x) &= \Sigma_x,\\
    E(\epsilon) &= 0 \quad\text{and} &\hspace{8em} V(\epsilon) &= \sigma_\epsilon^2.
  \end{alignedat}
\end{equation}
%
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    E(y) &= \mu_y, & V(y) &= \sigma_y^2,\\
    E(x) &=\mu_x, & C(x) &= \Sigma_x,\\
    E(\epsilon) &= 0 & \makebox[8em]{and\quad} V(\epsilon) &= \sigma_\epsilon^2.
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
%
\begin{equation}
  \begin{alignedat}{3}
    E(y) &= \mu_y, & & & V(y) &= \sigma_y^2,\\
    E(x) &=\mu_x, & & & C(x) &= \Sigma_x,\\
    E(\epsilon) &= 0 & \makebox[9em]{and} & & V(\epsilon) &= \sigma_\epsilon^2.
  \end{alignedat}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is very similar to what @campa suggested in a comment to the question. If I typeset both `align` and `equation`+`aligned` I can manually tune the `hspace` to make them match. This is exactly what I don't want to do.

Comment: I'm afraid the only choice is between a manual space adjustment and  a manual deleting of unwanted equation tags.